# get marketcap of a token using ethers.js

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, uniswap, pancakeswap

I'm wondering if we would get the marketcap of a token using ether.js, i made research those last few weeks i did not find a solution.

if someone could share an approach or a code, it will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of vague but I will still try to answer it.

You can use `ethers.js` library to interact with the blockchain using a node provider. This enables you to read the data from the blockchain. So you can get the total supply of a token by querying the appropriate contract using ethers.js.

However to get the market capitalisation, you need information external to the blockchain like the price of that token in a fiat currency. This would require you to query third party APIs. (You should do your own research here as suggesting something can be seen as marketing)

Again if your intent is to get the market capitalisation within the blockchain network without considering the real world (I am assuming this might be an option looking at your tags), you can check the price of the token in terms of network's native currency in the leading DEX in that network. To do this you just require the `ethers.js` library, a node provider to connect to and knowledge of the DEX functions to call to get the information you require.

Comment: Instead of using a 3rd party API to get token prices, OP could check the current price on a few DEXes (Uniswap v2 being the easiest) against stablecoins. Total supply is actually harder, as market cap is usually based on a "liquid" subset of the total supply (e.g. excluding tokens that vest in 4 years), which you can't really get just by looking at the total supply on the contract